# Eigenvalues of a block matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Let $\bar{\lambda}$ be the smallest eigenvalue of $$M=\Omega^{-1/2}Y'Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'Y\Omega^{-1/2}$$, where $\Omega$, $Y$, and $Z$ are $(l\times l)$, $(N\times l)$, and $(N \times k)$ matrices, respectively.

Then, define $$\bar{S}=(Z'Z)^{-1/2}Z'Yb_0(b_0'\Omega b_0)^{-1/2}$$ and $$\bar{T}=(Z'Z)^{-1/2}Z'Y\Omega^{-1}A_0(A_0'\Omega^{-1}A_0)^{-1/2}$$, where $b_0$ and $A_0$ are $(l\times 1)$ and $(l\times l)$ vector and matrix, respectively.

In a paper, the smallest eigenvalue $\bar{\lambda}$ is also the smallest eigenvalue of $$\left[\bar{S}, \bar{T}\right]'\left[\bar{S}, \bar{T}\right].$$

I think, since $\bar{S}'\bar{S}=\frac{b_0'Y'Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'Yb_0}{b_0'\Omega b_0}$ (this is very similar with the first matrix $M$), the statement holds by some properties of a block matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}\bar{S}'\bar{S}\quad\bar{S}'\bar{T} \\
\bar{T}'\bar{S} \quad \bar{T}'\bar{T}\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, I have no idea how the statement that $\bar{\lambda}$ is also the smallest eigenvalue of $\left[\bar{S}, \bar{T}\right]'\left[\bar{S}, \bar{T}\right]$ holds exactly.

Source: Moreira, M. J. (2003). A conditional likelihood ratio test for structural models. Econometrica, 71(4), 1033p.

Comment: This is because $[\bar{S}, \bar{T}]=(Z'Z)^{-1/2}Z'Y\Omega^{-1/2} W$, where $W$ is an orthogonal matrix. That is, $[\bar{S}, \bar{T}]'[\bar{S}, \bar{T}]$ is $W'MW$. Then, my question is that are the eigenvalues of $W'MW$ the same as those of $M$?